# HTML JS Canvas Game: Tile Collision Bug Makes Player Teleport Up

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection, tiles

I'm a beginner at game development and have been struggling with getting collision done right between an array of tiles and a player rectangle. This game features jumping and gravity. First of all the collision works, but is very clunky. Sometimes when the player ends up on top of a tile and a little to the edge, it will instantly teleport to either the right or left side (depending on what edge/corner) and fall of it. This also happens when colliding with the bottom of the tile; the player will instantly teleport to the side and go up further. From what I understand the tile collision detector confuses the collision with one or the other side because when the player hits the edge of a tile the detector reads it as if it collided with both and decides to place the player elsewhere base on the highest coordinate velocity (aka speedX and speedY). I figured this out by setting speedY = 0 every time it hits the top of a tile, which fixed the issue, but another one came out of it. Now, if the player is on top of a tile and then falls of and shortly strafe back, it doesn't collide with the tile's side, but it rather quickly goes back on top of it again.

I just need some tips on how i should resolve this, because everything I try leads to another problem. I've heard this is a common bug among developing 2D tile based games.

Here is a jsfiddle with the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/8121u356/

And here is the display of my entire code:

```
function startGame() {
    gameArea.start();
    actor = new player(32, 32, "green", 32, 32);
}

var mapArray = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

];

var levelRows = 20;
var levelCols = 20;
 var gameArea = {
     canvas : document.getElementById('canvas'),

     start : function() {
         this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
         document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
         requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
         window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
             gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
             gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
         });

         window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
             gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
             gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
         })
     },

     clear : function(){
         this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
     },
     render : function() {
         context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
         var tileSize = 32;
         for(i=0;i<levelRows;i++){
             for(j=0;j<levelCols;j++){
                 if(mapArray[i][j]==1){
                     context.fillStyle = "gray";
                     context.fillRect(j*tileSize,i*tileSize,tileSize,tileSize);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 };

function TileCollisionManager(object) {
    let tileSize = 32;
    let baseCol = Math.floor(object.x / tileSize);
    let baseRow = Math.floor(object.y / tileSize);
    let colOverlap = object.x % tileSize;
    let rowOverlap = Math.floor(object.y % tileSize);

    if (object.speedX > 0) { 
        if ((mapArray[baseRow][baseCol + 1] && !mapArray[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
            (mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol + 1] && !mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol] && rowOverlap)) {
            object.x = baseCol * tileSize;
        }
    }

    if (object.speedX < 0) {
        if ((!mapArray[baseRow][baseCol + 1] && mapArray[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
            (!mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol + 1] && mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol] && rowOverlap)) {
            object.x = (baseCol + 1) * tileSize;
        }
    }

    if (object.speedY > 0) { 
        if ((mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol] && !mapArray[baseRow][baseCol]) || 
            (mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol + 1] && !mapArray[baseRow][baseCol + 1] && colOverlap)) {
            object.y = ((baseRow) * tileSize);
            object.jumping = false;
            object.speedY = 0;
        }
    }

    if (object.speedY < 0) { 
        if ((!mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol] && mapArray[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
            (!mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol + 1] && mapArray[baseRow][baseCol + 1] && colOverlap)) {
            object.y = (baseRow + 1) * tileSize;
            object.speedY = 5;
        }
    }
 }
  function updateGameArea() {
      gameArea.clear();
      gameArea.render();
      actor.update();
      actor.newPos();
      actor.speedX = 0;
      actor.speedY += actor.gravity;


      if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[39]) {
          actor.speedX = 4;
      }
      if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[37]) {
          actor.speedX = -4;
      }
      if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[32]) { 
          if (!actor.jumping) {
              actor.jumping = true;
              actor.speedY = -actor.speed * 3;
          }
      }


      TileCollisionManager(actor);
      requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
  }


  function player (width, height, color, x, y) { 
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.speedX=0;
      this.speedY=0;
      this.gravity=0.3;
      this.speed=3;
      this.jumping=false;
      this.color = color;
      this.update = function () {
          ctx = gameArea.context;
          ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
          ctx.fillRect(
              this.x,
              this.y,
              this.width, this.height);
      };
      this.newPos = function () {
          this.x += this.speedX;
          this.y += this.speedY;
      };
```

Comment: your code has an issue that you don't set speedY to zero when it hits the bottom "Collision with the bottom of a tile" this in turns will trigger the upwards collision detection when the motion is down or not moving at all. Causing odd behavior.

Comment: Another potential bug is that you let the user jump once when they are falling. This can result in feeling that there is bug in the collision stuff when it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A quick fix for you.

I have seen you post this question for the 3rd time. You are not getting an answer because the best solution is rather a lot of code, complex, and requires a lot of changes to your code.

So what I have done is create a very quick and simple solution.

#### Solve collisions in the correct order.

Rather than check the position at the end of a move, I changed the code to check at every pixel moved. This is needed as you have to find the collisions in the correct order as the player moves from one position to the next. If you hit a wall on the side before the top or bottom, or the other way around it makes a difference, and is what is causing you to have problems. You checked x first then y, which for many situation is the wrong way around.

I also added a object to the actor called `canMove` It has 4 properties that are set at the start of each frame and are used to prevent the player moving in a direction that is blocked. If you let the player move in a blocked direction it will get stuck on the wall while you have the key down in that direction.

#### I hacked into your code

Sorry I made a bit of a mess but am short on time.

Also to help me write the changes I made a few other mods, I scaled that game to fit the window (the scaling and resize is all done in the `clear` function). I changed the keyboard interface to prevent default on keys pressed and set up arrow to jump as well as space (I hate using space to jump :P). Also change the map to use strings as it is a pain typing in changes as an array.

I was not sure how you wanted the actor to react when it is hit on the head. I made it so that it bounces down at the same speed as it moves up, but it does make it harder to jump and slide into narrow passages.

So I think I have most of it done, so you can move on with your game.

If you have questions, ask in the comments.

```js
   // NOTE  var | 0 is the same as Math.floor(var)

var mapArray = [
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#  ###             #",
        "#           #      #",
        "#       ##  #####  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#    ##            #",
        "#      ##          #",
        "#                  #",
        "#      #####       #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#       #####      #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#       #     ##   #",
        "#      ###         #",
        "#     ##### ##     #",
        "####################",
    ].map(row => row.split("").map(cell=>cell==="#" ? 1 : 0));


    var levelRows = 20;
    var levelCols = 20;
    var tileX = 32;
    var tileY = 32;
    var gameArea = {
     canvas : document.getElementById('canvas'),
     ctx : document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d"),
     keys : {  // set them here so that can block defaults
        "37" : false,
        "38" : false,     // also jump
        "39" : false,
        "32" : false,     // jump
     },

     start : function() {
         document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
         requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
         function keyEvent(e) { 
             if(gameArea.keys["" + e.keyCode] !== undefined){
              gameArea.keys["" + e.keyCode] = e.type === "keydown" 
              e.preventDefault();
             }
         }
         addEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);
         addEventListener('keyup', keyEvent);
         focus();
        },

        clear(){
            var minSize = Math.min(innerWidth,innerHeight);
            if (this.ctx.canvas.width !== minSize|| this.ctx.canvas.height !== minSize) {
                this.ctx.canvas.width = minSize;
                this.ctx.canvas.height = minSize;
            }
                
            this.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            
            // the next line scales the canvas rendering to fit.
            this.ctx.setTransform(
                minSize / (levelCols * tileX),
                0,
                0,
                minSize/ (levelRows * tileY),
                0,0
            );
        },
        render() {
            var ctx = this.ctx;
            for(i=0;i<levelRows;i++){
                for(j=0;j<levelCols;j++){
                    if(mapArray[i][j]==1){
                        ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
                        ctx.fillRect(j*tileX,i*tileY,tileX,tileY);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    function updateGameArea() { 
        gameArea.clear();
        actor.canMove.check();
        actor.speedX = 0;
        if(actor.canMove.down){
            actor.speedY += actor.gravity;
        }

        if (gameArea.keys[39] && actor.canMove.right) {
            actor.speedX = 4;
        }
        if (gameArea.keys[37]  && actor.canMove.left) {
            actor.speedX = -4;
        }
        if (actor.canMove.up && (gameArea.keys[32] || gameArea.keys[38])) { //jump
            if (!actor.jumping) {
                actor.jumping = true;
                actor.speedY = -actor.speed * 3;
            }
        }
        actor.move();  // collision is done here
        
        gameArea.render();
        actor.draw();

        requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
    }

    function Player (width, height, color, x, y) { //player component
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speedX=0;
        this.speedY=0;
        this.gravity=0.3;
        this.speed=3;
        this.jumping=false;
        this.color = color;
        this.canMove = {
           left : true,
           right : true,
           up : true,
           down : true,
           actor : this,
           clear(){
              this.left = true;
              this.right = true;
              this.up = true;
              this.down = true;
           },
           check(){
              this.clear();
              var x = this.actor.x | 0;
              var y = this.actor.y | 0;
              var cx = x / tileX | 0;
              var cy = y / tileY | 0;
              if(x % tileX === 0){
                 if(getMap(cx-1,cy) === 1){                 
                   this.left = false;
                   if(y % tileY !== 0 && getMap(cx-1,cy +1) === 1){
                      this.left = false;
                   }
                 }
                 if(getMap(cx+1,cy) === 1){
                   this.right = false;
                   if(y % tileY !== 0 && getMap(cx+1,cy +1) === 1){
                      this.right = false;
                   }
                 }
              }
              if(y % tileY === 0){
                 if(getMap(cx,cy-1) === 1){                 
                   this.up = false;
                   if(x % tileX !== 0 && getMap(cx+1,cy -1) === 1){
                      this.up = false;
                   }
                 }
                 if(getMap(cx,cy+1) === 1){
                   this.down = false;
                   if(x % tileX !== 0 && getMap(cx+1,cy +1) === 1){
                      this.down = false;
                   }
                 }
              }
           }
        };

        this.draw = function () {
            var ctx = gameArea.ctx;
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(  this.x,this.y, this.width, this.height);
        };
        this.move = function() {
          var x = this.x;
          var y = this.y;
          var sx = this.speedX;
          var sy = this.speedY;
          var speed = Math.sqrt(sx * sx + sy * sy);
          if(speed > 0){
            sx /= speed;
            sy /= speed;
            for(var i = 0; i < speed; i++){
              var xx = (x + sx * i) | 0;
              var yy = (y + sy * i) | 0;
              var cx = xx / tileX | 0;
              var cy = yy / tileY | 0;
              if(sy > 0){
                if(getMap(cx,cy+1) === 1 || (xx % tileX !== 0 && getMap(cx + 1,cy+1))){
                  this.y = y = cy * tileY;
                  this.speedY = sy = speed < 4 ? 0 : -3;
                  this.jumping = false;
                }
              }else if(sy < 0){
                if(getMap(cx,cy) === 1 || (xx % tileX !== 0 && getMap(cx + 1,cy))){
                  cy += 1;
                  this.y = y = cy * tileY;
                  this.speedY = sy = -sy;  // changing -sy to 0 will stick momentarily to the roof.
                }
              }
              if(sx > 0){
                if(getMap(cx+1,cy) === 1 ||  (yy % tileY !== 0 && getMap(cx + 1,cy+1))){
                  this.x = x = cx * tileX;
                  this.speedX = sx = 0;
                }

              }else if(sx < 0){
                if(getMap(cx,cy) === 1 || (yy % tileY !== 0 && getMap(cx,cy+1))){
                  cx += 1;
                  this.x = x = cx * tileX;
                  this.speedX = sx = 0;
                }          
              }
            }
          }
          this.x += this.speedX;
          this.y += this.speedY;
        }
    }

    function getMap(x,y){
      if(y < 0 || y >= levelRows || x < 0 || x >= levelCols){
         return 1;
      }
      return mapArray[y][x];
    }
 

    gameArea.start();
    actor = new Player(32, 32, "green", 32, 32);
```

```css
canvas { 
   position : absolute;
   top : 0px;
   left : 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow you're a legend! This fixed everything like a charm, thanks! I have a question though. Is it still possible to change the string based map array into an integer two dimensional array? I will be using a tilesheet image for the tiles and I have a code that can read each tile based on those numbers. Also I noticed this bug still persists but only when going on the top right corner of a tile. I beleive I should be able to fix that myself once I understand the code a bit more. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlanRostem The map is only string in the source. The code `.map(row => r,,,` converts it back to the same array as you had before. 2D array of 0, and 1. The solution is not perfect as all it has done is move the problem from 32 by 32 blocks down to a 1 by 1 pixel.. The best solution is converting the tile map to a vector map (internal to code only) and doing a vector intercept, one vector for each corner of the actor's box. That will give perfect collisions ( and works for all shapes)

Comment: I got the array working! I'd like to know how to get started with a system with vectors, because I've been searching everywhere without any luck. Also the idea of it working with any shapes sounds amazing. Hope it's not too much to ask. If not I can stick with your move-checking system because it is exactly what I was looking for.