# Pure Javascript Tile map collision detection

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am making a tile based game with a traditional method(two for loops) and i am trying to write collision detection but nothing works. I want the blue square to stay in the screen and be on top of the tiles after you hit start. I have encountered a virus looking for a solution. Please help me stack overflow community.

The code:

```js
const context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
const person = new rectangle(100,100,20,20,'blue');
setInterval(update_all,10);
var next_block_x = 0;
var next_block_y = 0;
var block_size = 50;
var moving = false;
const tile_map = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1]
];
function rectangle(x,y,w,h,col){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.col = col;
    this.update = function(){
        context.fillStyle = this.col;
        context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
        context.stroke();
    }
}
function block(x,y,col){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.col = col;
    context.fillStyle = this.col;
    context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,block_size,block_size);
    context.stroke();
}
function update_tile_map(){
    for(i=0;i<tile_map.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<tile_map[i].length;j++){
            if(tile_map[i][j] == 1){
                new block(next_block_x,next_block_y,'red');
            }
            next_block_x += block_size;
        }
        next_block_x = 0;
        next_block_y += block_size
    }
    next_block_x = 0;
    next_block_y = 0;
}
function clear(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
}
function start(){
    moving = true;
}
function stop(){
    moving = false;
}
function update_all(){
    clear();
    update_tile_map();
    person.update();
    if(moving != false){
        person.y ++;
    }
}
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color:lightgrey;
    border: 4px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='start()'>START</button>
<button onclick='stop()'>STOP</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width='300' height='300'></canvas>
```

Comment: The follow has a robust solution for collision detection in side view tile based platforms https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920237/3877726

Comment: Any other solutions?

Comment: That Looks like more code then needed to fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an if statement to check if the block has hit the wall:

```
if (person.y<300) person.y ++; else person.y = 0
```

```js
const context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
const person = new rectangle(100,100,20,20,'blue');
setInterval(update_all,10);

var block_size = 50;
var moving = false;
const tile_map = [
    [1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1]
];
function rectangle(x,y,w,h,col){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.col = col;
    this.update = function(){
        context.fillStyle = this.col;
        context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
        context.stroke();
    }
}


function clear(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
}
function start(){
    moving = true;
}
function stop(){
    moving = false;
}
function update_all(){
    clear();

    person.update();
    if(moving != false){
        if (person.y<300) person.y ++; else person.y = 0
    }
}
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color:lightgrey;
    border: 4px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='start()'>START</button>
<button onclick='stop()'>STOP</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width='300' height='300'></canvas>
```

Comment: @Justiniscoding Perhaps you could clarify the question?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I can use this with the tile position for the collision detection